# Userform Error in Excel When updating record with decimals

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization, userform

I've written a userform that edits records from an Excel table.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ActiveRow As Long
ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
...
Me.Controls("exchangeRate").Value = Cells(ActiveRow, 21)
```

In the userform the value shows up as expected. We copy this value from our bank, and there for receive a long value with lots of decimal places.

Example:

> 10,8116705323301

So the userform shows this value, no problem. But when i save this value again, the comma is removed.

> 108116705323301

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("sheet").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
Dim ActiveRow As Long
ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
   Cells(ActiveRow, 21).Value = exchangeRate.Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("sheet").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, Password:="xxx"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. So if you do `Debug.Print Me.Controls("exchangeRate").Value` you get the number without the comma? Are the comma your decimal separator? Make sure also VBA gets the value as decimal , because by default, VBA decimal separator **is not** the comma, but the dot.

Comment: >11,1119203934117

This is the debug output. How do i make sure VBA captures the value as decimal , ?

Comment: If the output is correct, then it's right. So when you do `exchangeRate.Value` is when it looses the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TextBox values are strings**

There are some points causing your issue due to your *local number settings* (deviating from VBA's number formatting):

1. Apparently your `Application.DecimalSeparator` equals ► `,` and **not** the defaulting comma `.` as used in *VBA*
   (in many middle European countries the default comma is represented by a column `,`, whereas the local `Application.ThousandsSeparator` is a point `.`).
2. Initially you are assigning a cell value of double type to a textbox only capable to hold text.
   VBA prefers to convert this number (VBA internal value: `10.8116705323301`) to a locally formatted string 
   displayed as `10,8116705323301`.
3. Writing a basically *numeric string* back to a cell will be interpreted as number, but following the English default settings.
   If there appears an English ThousandsSeparator (i.e. a colon `,`) in a numeric stringthis will be neglected as unnecessary deco, 
   thus resulting in a cell value of `108116705323301` (assuming a local numberformat of "0").

**Remedy**

As I suppose you intend to continue displaying the value in your local format within Userform,
you'll have to convert the control value to a number (double type). If you are sure that your
`Application.DecimalSeparator` equals "," and not to the English colon, you could recode your **`CommandButton1_Click()`** event as follow:

```
    ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet").Cells(activeRow, 21).Value = Val(Replace(Me.TextBox1, "," , "."))
```

BTW Always use fully qualified range references; note that it would even preferrable to use a sheet's `CodeName` instead it's
normal sheet name that could be overwritten too easily by other users.

Comment: Thanks, solution verified!